# Powershell - get a simple list of files (with their path included) using Get-ChildItem

Tags: windows, powershell, file, search, scripting

I want a Powershell script that outputs files found through recursive with a modified date after a certain time.

At the moment, it's a single command like this;

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge "01/01/2020 19:57:00" }
```

However, the output is not easy to work  with as I get something like this:

```
            Directory: C:\Test
            Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
            ----                -------------         ------ ----
            ------        02/01/2020    15:58       69005864 x.exe
            ------        02/01/2020    15:17         144182 y.pptx
            ------        02/01/2020    17:34       57452572 z.exe
```

I would like my output instead to be:

```
C:\Test\x.exe
C:\Test\y.pptx
C:\Test\z.exe
```

Along with files from all the other folders. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: You are looking for the `FullName` property. `[code] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question, especially coming from a Command Prompt background where you can easily type `dir /s/b` and get similar results.  Here's what I typically do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge "01/01/2020 19:57:00" } | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
```

Actually, I use aliases to reduce typing:

```
dir -r | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -ge "01/01/2020 19:57:00" } | %{ $_.FullName }
```

Or if you want to use `Select-Object` as @Ash suggested:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge "01/01/2020 19:57:00" } | Select-Object -Property FullName | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize
```

With aliases:

```
dir -r | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -ge "01/01/2020 19:57:00" } | Select-Object FullName | ft -a -h
```

The latter is just a bit less concise.

Comment: My suggestion was fine as it was, before it was made less concise.

Comment: The OP asked for a simple list.  Simply adding `Select-Object ...` adds headers by default which doesn't return a simple list.

Comment: Not with `-ExpandProperty` as stated in my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The output of powershell is kind of an illusion.  It's really outputting objects with groups of properties.  Some object types have format files that control how they look.  One way to see the list of the real properties is to pipe it to `format-list *` or `fl *` for short.  You can see the `FullName` property here showing the full path to the file.  Even in this listing, the `VersionInfo` property is getting extra formatting from some format file.

```
get-childitem foo | fl *


PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\users\js\foo\foo
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\users\js\foo
PSChildName       : foo
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : False
Mode              : -a----
VersionInfo       : File:             C:\users\js\foo\foo
                    InternalName:
                    OriginalFilename:
                    FileVersion:
                    FileDescription:
                    Product:
                    ProductVersion:
                    Debug:            False
                    Patched:          False
                    PreRelease:       False
                    PrivateBuild:     False
                    SpecialBuild:     False
                    Language:

BaseName          : foo
Target            : {}
LinkType          :
Name              : foo
Length            : 4
DirectoryName     : C:\users\js\foo
Directory         : C:\users\js\foo
IsReadOnly        : False
Exists            : True
FullName          : C:\users\js\foo\foo
Extension         :
CreationTime      : 1/2/2020 1:44:37 PM
CreationTimeUtc   : 1/2/2020 6:44:37 PM
LastAccessTime    : 1/2/2020 1:44:37 PM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 1/2/2020 6:44:37 PM
LastWriteTime     : 1/2/2020 1:44:37 PM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 1/2/2020 6:44:37 PM
Attributes        : Archive
```

Another example.  Usually the headers match the property names:

```
dir | select mode,lastwritetime,length,name

Mode   LastWriteTime         length Name
----   -------------         ------ ----
d----- 1/3/2020 11:35:44 AM         foo2
-a---- 1/2/2020 3:53:32 PM   4      0.txt
-a---- 1/2/2020 3:53:37 PM   4      9.txt
-a---- 12/24/2019 1:45:07 PM 42     file.json
-a---- 12/23/2019 2:26:40 PM 63     file.json~
-a---- 1/2/2020 1:44:37 PM   4      foo
-a---- 1/2/2020 3:54:14 PM   50     listnum.ps1
-a---- 1/2/2020 3:53:15 PM   41     listnum.ps1~
```

Answer (score 0):

`gci -File -Recurse -Name`

`gci` being an alias for `GetChild-Item`

This will give you exactly the output you want.